# Using Codeigniter date helper to get timezone location

Tags: php, codeigniter, time, timezone

I'm using the Codeigniter date helper for timezone functions. I want to display a user's timezone location based on their timezone reference that I'm saving in the database.

**Example:**

Take a timezone reference `UP1` and return the corresponding location `(UTC + 1:00) Berlin, Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris, Rome`. Date helper does not have a function for that.

The function could be executed like this..

```
echo timezone_location('UP1');
```

which will echo

```
(UTC + 1:00) Berlin, Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris, Rome
```

Codeigniter's timezone data exists in the folder `system/langauge/englishdate_lang.php` but I'm not sure how to access that to build the function. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CI stores it the language file [system/language/english/date_lang.php](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/language/english/date_lang.php)

So you could do the following

```
// load the language file
$this->lang->load('date', 'english');
// will output (UTC -12:00) Baker/Howland Island
echo $this->lang->line('UM12');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->load->helper('language');
$this->lang->load('date', 'english');
echo (lang('UM7')); //gives "(UTC -7:00) Mountain Standard Time"
```